Man/demon(?) found in the woods covered in tattoos
I saw this sometime between 2014-2016. City is falling or something big is happening, a group of random strangers get into an ambulance and drive out of town to a mansion where they find food, shelter, a safe room etc.. Then something happens, someone runs away? They go into the woods out the back of the mansion and find a white man crawling on the ground speaking gibberish and covered in tattoos with black eyes. I think it was an American pilot show.

You're describing the pilot for The After, (2014), which Chris Carter did for Amazon.

The opening of the episode has our series protagonist, a French
  wannabe actress, stuck in an elevator with a small group of people.
  The power has gone out in the building and they quickly pry open the
  doors and exit into the buildings car park. Unfortunately, a security
  gate prevents them from being able to leave the car park.
...
After a tension-free escape from the car park, the group use an
  ambulance to drive through a group of people on the street who
  illogically want to tip over the vehicle.
...
In the ambulance the group drive to the home of an older lady with the
  group who happens to live in a large mansion.
...
After being chased out of the house by looters, the group find
  themselves in a nearby forest where they encounter a humanoid creature
  who looks part grey alien/part Sméagol. We see that the creature has a
  number of tattoos on him, which, in a greater coincidence than the
  shared birthdays, are the same as tattoos that members of the group
  have themselves.

